# Find the sum of last 5 consecutive numbers in the excel in each row

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[[image: Need to calculate the last 5 non zero consecutive value in each row]]

I need to calculate the sum of the last 5 consecutive non-zero values in each row.

I've tried the below ,

```
=SUM(TAKE(FILTER(B2:K2,(B2:K2)*(B2:K2<>"")),,-5))
```

For example, for the first row of data (AR) it should calculate the sum from M5 to M1 and for the third row (AW) from M7 to M3.

Any idea how to resolve this?

[image: Sample Output]

Comment: Also, it is not clear if this is an excel exercise or a clear sql one. You should make up your mind which one you want to use.

Comment: thirs row ?please correct this typo and add sample data and desired outcome as text.

Comment: excel exercise @Shadow

Comment: It seemed fairly clear to me and I did have an answer but never mind.

Comment: It was fairly easy as well, one could use the following formula: `=LET(α, TEXTSPLIT(CONCAT(IF(B2:K2=0,"|",B2:K2&",")),"|",,1),φ, LEN(α),δ, MAX(φ),ε, FILTER(α, δ=φ),Θ, SEQUENCE(,MAX(LEN(ε)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(ε,",",)))),Σ, SUM(--TAKE(TEXTSPLIT(TEXTAFTER(","&ε,",",Θ),","),,-5)),Σ)`

Comment: Or if you want to spill with one single dynamic array then: `=BYROW(B2:K10,LAMBDA(x, LET(α, TEXTSPLIT(CONCAT(IF(x=0,"|",x&",")),"|",,1),φ, LEN(α),δ, MAX(φ),ε, FILTER(α, δ=φ),Θ, SEQUENCE(,MAX(LEN(ε)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(ε,",",)))),Σ, SUM(--TAKE(TEXTSPLIT(TEXTAFTER(","&ε,",",Θ),","),,-5)),Σ)))`

Comment: This was mine - contrasting approaches! =LET(range,B2:K2,runs,SCAN(0,SEQUENCE(1,10,10,-1),LAMBDA(a,c,IF(INDEX(range,c)=0,0,a+1))),
posOf5,XMATCH(5,runs),SUM(INDEX(range,11-posOf5):INDEX(range,15-posOf5)))